# JavaFXで作られたJavaプログラムの実行方法がわからない

Tags: java, swing, javafx

以下のリポジトリからGitHub CLIでZipのダウンロードし、jcommon-1.0.23.jarをダブルクリックで実行できません、他に方法があるのでしょうか？大変、お手数ですが、どなた、ご存じの方、教えて頂けでしょうか？
調べたんですが、どうも分かりません。初心者という事もあって、誠に大変、失礼します。

https://github.com/Suwadith/Slot-Machine-JavaSwing-OOP-GUI

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

スロットマシン本体はソースコードの形でしか提供されていないので、自前でビルドする必要があります。
(`jcommon-1.0.23.jar` というのはスロットマシン本体ではなく、スロットマシンが利用しているライブラリーです。)

このプロジェクトを素直にビルド&実行するには[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/ja-jp/idea/)と、Oracle JDK8が必要です。
(Oracle JDK8 が必要なのは、JavaFX を利用しているからです。これ以外のJDK8にはJavaFXが同梱されていません([参考](https://qiita.com/yamadamn/items/bb813dccaa1dc5585c9b))。Oracle JDK8が用意できない場合、別途 [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) が利用できるようにセットアップする必要があるでしょう)

これらが用意できれば、IntelliJ IDEAでこのプロジェクトを開き、利用するJDKをOracle JDK8に設定すればビルド&実行できます。

---

InelliJ IDEA を用いず、コマンドラインからビルドするには:

```
javac -cp jcommon-1.0.23.jar:jfreechart-1.0.19.jar src/OOP_CW2/*.java
```

実行するには:

```
java -cp jcommon-1.0.23.jar:jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:src OOP_CW2.GraphicalUserInterface
```

(Windowsだと `:` でなく `;` で区切る必要があったかもしれません(未確認))

---

前述の通り、Oracle JDK8 を用いないのであれば JavaFX(OpenJFX) を [セットアップ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) する必要があります。

Maven プロジェクトとしてセットアップしたものを以下に作ってみました([参考](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)):

- https://github.com/yukihane/Slot-Machine-JavaSwing-OOP-GUI

上のリポジトリをチェックアウトして、Windowsであれば次のコマンドを実行すれば起動すると思います:

```
mvnw.cmd clean javafx:run
```

Mavenプロジェクトとして構成するのに必要な [pom.xml](https://github.com/yukihane/Slot-Machine-JavaSwing-OOP-GUI/blob/feature/for-openjdk/pom.xml) はこちらです:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.github.yukihane.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>slot-machine-javaswing-oop-gui</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Slot-Machine-JavaSwing-OOP-GUI</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <javafx-maven-plugi.version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugi.version>
    <openjfx.version>22</openjfx.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx-maven-plugi.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>OOP_CW2.GraphicalUserInterface</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: IntelliJ IDEAが必要なんですね。全く知りませんでした。回答も初心者に分かりやすい説明で誠にありがとうござしました。まだまだ、勉強が必要です。

Comment: コマンドラインからのビルド、実行方法を追記しました。

Comment: ファイル名が無効です: src\OOP_CW2\*.javaと出ますが、具体的方法が出して頂き、大変、助かりました。再び、ありごうございました。

Comment: 実行環境(例えばWindow10のPowerShell上で実行した、など)を質問に追記してもらえれば追加で情報を提示できるかもしれません。

Comment: PowerShell上ではPathが通っていない感じですね。多分、コマンドプロントは、何故か、昨日と違うエラーですね。うーん。原因が分かりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。'mvnw.cmd' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。動きません。

Comment: 実行しているディレクトリ配下に [`mvnw.cmd`](https://github.com/yukihane/Slot-Machine-JavaSwing-OOP-GUI/blob/feature/for-openjdk/mvnw.cmd) が存在していることを確認してみてください。存在していないのであれば、文中に記載したリポジトリが正しくチェックアウトできていませんのでそこからやり直してみてください。

Comment: mvnw.cmdは確かにありますが、今度はエラーが連発して、分かりません。長く、親切に対応して頂き、誠にありがとうございます。ここで一旦、保留とさせて下さい。ダウンロードして、2~3回しましたが、やはり変わりません。

Answer (score -1):

コマンドラインでjarファイルを実行するには先頭に-jarを指定します
また、実行環境がパワーシェルのようですが、こちらでは`;`がコマンドの区切り文字として機能するため、`”;”`と文字列に変換する必要があります

```
java -jar -cp jcommon-1.0.23.jar”;”jfreechart-1.0.19.jar”;”src OOP_CW2.GraphicalUserInterface
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。Error: Unable to access jarfile OOP_CW2.GraphicalUserInterface　動きません。

Comment: @Rookie 実行対象のMainクラスがjarファイルに存在し、かつ `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` ファイルの `Main-Class` セクションで指定されている場合、 `-jar` オプションを指定することでコマンドラインでのメインクラス指定を省略できます([参考](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#java.2hehoK))。ただ、今回はそのような状況ではありません。